# How to fix this SerializableError? Error serializing `.middlewareAPI` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".undefined cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, nextjs-image

I'm trying to get data from a URL endpoint and every time I get this error:

[image: SerializableError]

How to fix this SerializableError?

> Error serializing `.middlewareAPI` returned from `getServerSideProps`
> in "/". Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only
> return JSON serializable data types.

Here is my function:

```
exports.SerializableError = SerializableError;

function isSerializableProps(page, method, input) {
  if (!(0, \_isPlainObject.isPlainObject)(input)) {
    throw new SerializableError(page, method, "", `Props must be returned as a plain object from ${method}: \`{ props: { ... } }\` (received: \`${(0, \_isPlainObject.getObjectClassLabel)(input)}\`).\`);
  }

  function visit(visited, value, path) {
    if (visited.has(value)) {
      throw new SerializableError(page, method, path, `Circular references cannot be expressed in JSON (references: \`${visited.get(value) || "(self)"}\`).\`);
    }
    visited.set(value, path);
  }

  function isSerializable(refs, value, path) {
    const type = typeof value;

    if (value === null || type === "boolean" || type === "number" || type === "string") {
      return true;
    }
    if (type === null) {
      // Replaced undefined with null
      value = null;
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

In my local environment, I am unable to run this code.

Comment: First:  `typeof` returns a string, it will never return `null`,  so you probably meant -> `if (type === 'undefined')`, if you want to check for null, you would also just do `value === null`..